# How to iterate over an array of hashes in Ruby and return all of the values of a specific key in a string

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerable

I'm currently trying to iterate over an array of hashes, and return all of the values of the "name" key in a string.  Here's the array:

```
foods = 

  [
    { name: 'Dan Dan Noodles', cuisine: 'Sichuan', heat_level: 8 },
    { name: 'Nashville Hot Chicken', cuisine: 'American', heat_level: 7 },
    { name: 'Panang Curry', cuisine: 'Thai', heat_level: 4 },
  ]
```

Here's what I'm currently doing, and I'm not totally sure why it's not working!

```
  foods.each do |food|
    food.each do |k, v|
      if food == :name
        "#{v}"
      end
    end
  end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `food == :name` will always be `false` because `food` is a hash and `:name` is a symbol. You need `if k == :name`, but the selected answer gives a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Enumerable#map for this:

```rb
p foods.map { |f| f[:name] }
```

The code you tried to use did not produce any output or create any objects, and it was not necessary to use a second loop to access a single element of a hash.